# Setup main function in eclipse makefile project

Tags: c++, eclipse

I created a new HalloWorld Makefile Project. There is a HalloWorld.cpp with my main function.
Now I have a file /src/startup.cpp that conains a main function. Now I want to use the main function from /src/startup.cpp

Where can I tell eclipse to use that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the following in the file Makefile at the project root

```
CXXFLAGS= -g -O0
CXX=g++

all: bin bin/myprog

bin/myprog: bin/startup.o
    $(CXX) -o bin/myprog bin/startup.o

bin/startup.o: src/startup.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o bin/startup.o -c src/startup.cpp

bin:
    mkdir bin

clean:
    rm bin/startup.o
    rm bin/myprog
```

Comment: So i relay have to write all the makefiles myself? Okay. Thanks.